# Article as homepage without menu connected

Tags: joomla, menu, assign, joomla-article

Is that possible to make a single article as homepage, but not connected with any menu item?

I'm using Joomla 1.7

Comment: Try publish a module in a position and load that position on the page you want it to display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No that is NOT technically possible - Joomla is menu driven.

But you could create a Menu Item (of type Article -> Single Article View) set it to be the default item (so it is your home page) and set the main menu module to not be shown on that page (if that is what you are trying to achieve).

The other option - is to create a new menu - for example called 'hidden'. Add your new menu item to this menu, and don't even have a module for this menu.

One or other of these options should do what you need.

Comment: Which one of the two options did you use?  And please don't forget to 'accept' the answer (click the tick / check mark on the left) to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Second option, with second, hidden menu.

Answer (score 0):

In the article list, there is a flag that can be activated that says "Home Page".
That makes the article to be shown in the content area of your home page... just that.